# Как удалять элементы (например кнопку или строку ввода) в tkinter python?

Tags: python, tkinter

Я хочу сделать скрипт похожий на момент ввода логина и пароля. Базы данных нет, поэтому использую if, хочу сделать так, чтобы при входе окно менялось и убирало элементы прошлого варианта окна (поля ввода пароля, логина и кнопки вход/выход. Изменение размера окна сделал, но не могу придумать как сделать момент удаления, хочу его сделать в функции intro()

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x500")
root.title("ANCMES.login")
root.iconbitmap(default="D:/ANCMES/Login.ico")
root.maxsize(300, 500)
root.minsize(300, 500)
def log():
    for c in range(3): root.columnconfigure(index=c, weight=1)
    for r in range(4): root.rowconfigure(index=r, weight=1)

    login = Entry()
    Label(text="Логин:").grid(row=0, column=0)
    login.insert(0, "Hello World")
    login.grid(row=0, column=1, ipadx=30)
    password = Entry()
    Label(text="Пароль:").grid(row=1, column=0)
    password.grid(row=1, column=1, ipadx=30)

    button_enter = Button(text="Вход")
    button_enter.grid(row=2, column=1)
    button_enter.config(command=intro)

    def fin():
        root.destroy()
        print("Завершение приложения")

    button_exit = Button(text="EXIT")
    button_exit.grid(row=3, column=1)
    button_exit.config(command=fin)

def intro():
    root.geometry("1280x800")
    root.maxsize(1280, 800)
    root.minsize(1280, 800)
    login.delete()
    

log()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Можете вложить виджеты внутрь фрейма(контейнер), и затем управлять фреймами, скрывая или отображая их. Или скрывать каждый элемент по отдельности, т.е. у нас изначально есть все элементы на окне, но при нажатии кнопки часть интерфейса становится видимым, часть скрытым.